# msg.mentions.members.first(); Not working (Discord.js V14)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

so im trying to make a sort of `!Ban @User` Command. i tried using
`const target = msg.mentions.members.first();` but i guess that is outdated because it didnt work? currently im still testing and trying to get it work before doing a !ban @user command.

Heres my current code:

```
if (msg.content === "mention") {
        const target = msg.mentions.members.first();
        if (!target) {
            msg.delete()
            const bruhresponsee = await msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}>, please provide a user in your message!`)

            setTimeout(() => {
                bruhresponsee.delete()
            }, 5000);
            return;
        


    }

    if (target) {
        console.log(target)
    }
}
```

it doesnt log the target, and idk what to do.

im incredibly new to discord.js so im guessing it might be outdated

thank you in advance

Comment: I think the problem is more likely to be in the `msg.content === "mention"` part. You are doing a hardcoded check to see if the content of the message is `"mention"`, but in your issue you say you are trying to use `"!ban @User"` - those strings do not match. Should you be trying to check if `msg.mentions.members.length > 0`?

Comment: uh could u edit my code cause i dont really understand what your trying to say 

Comment: You're checking if the message is "mention" exactly. There is no possible way for your message to both be exactly "mention" *and* have a mentioned user ("mention @user")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your if statement's logic.

You're currently checking if the content of your message is the string "mention", which will only trigger the code when someone in chat types exactly the word "mention".

You need to modify your if statement to:

```
// check if there is at least one mention
if(msg.mentions.members.size > 0) {

  const target = msg.mentions.members.first();

  // you're already checking if a mention exists in your if statement
  // so you can get rid of the if(!target) statement

  console.log(target)

}
```